# What is unicode character turned AE ᴂ(U+1D02) used for?

Tags: ipa, phonetic-symbols, unicode

The near-open front unrounded vowel is written as æ(U+00E6), commented as "Latin Small Letter Ae". But I found the character ᴂ(U+1D02) commented as "Latin Small Letter **Turned** Ae" which is a new char created by rotating æ 180 degrees and the character locates at the Phonetic Extensions block which means it is used mainly for phonetic purpose. So, I wonder what is the character ᴂ used for in phonetics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uralicist notation (sometimes called the Uralic Phonetic Alphabet) rotates vowel characters to indicate a shortened, centralized, or reduced form of the vowel. [The original proposal to the Unicode Consortium](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2002/02141-n2419-uralic-phonetic.pdf) confirms that was the reason for the turned vowel glyphs, including turned æ.

That's also why we have codepoints like ᴞ, for a reduced version of ü (a high front rounded vowel).

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question: where can I find unicode proposals like the document you mentioned? And thanks again.

Comment: @C.K. They're officially listed somewhere on the Unicode site, but I find it easier to access them by going to the Wikipedia page for the block in question (every block has one); they should all be listed by date, author, and range at the bottom of the page. That's where I found this one.

Comment: @C.K. have a look at the Unicode Technical Committee Document Registry at https://www.unicode.org/L2/

Comment: @devio Thank you! That's what I want!